# Grid to be displayed as popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dojo

Here is the grid as follows:

```
 if (responseJSON) {
     showObjects(['anTable']);
     showObjects(['dist']);
     $('gridtab').innerHTML = '';
     var wordStructure = [{
         field: 'alpha',
         name: 'Alpa Dictionary',
         width: '200px'
     }, {
         field: 'numbers',
         name: 'Number Format',
         width: '200px'
     }, {
         field: 'words',
         name: 'Normal words',
         width: '200px'
     }];
     var wordStore = [];
 }
```

Here is the Html table as follows which is to be displayed as popup with the grid above:

```
<table cellpadding='15' cellspacing='15' id="dist" style="display: none; width:auto">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="gridtab" style="width: 400%; font-size: 11pt; font-family: arial; border: 1px solid #fff; padding: 5px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" preventCache='true' useCache='false' cacheContent='false' onclick="getSelectedNormalWords();">Ok</button>
        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" preventCache='true' useCache='false' cacheContent='false'>Cancel</button>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`showOjects(['dist'])` is just displaying grid with table but I want to display it as popup.

```
function showObjects(objArray) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        $(objArray[i]).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not related to your answer, but pop-ups are getting out of style. Many browsers blocks pop-up. They also have many disadvantages, that's why more and more people switched pop-ups to modals.

Comment: Daniel Cheung thank you soo much for the response. but i need to dispaly it as popup according to my project.

Comment: When you say "popup", do you mean a completely separate browser window, or just something that pops up over the existing content? For example, would something like a Dijit Dialog work?

Comment: @ jason  Its something that pops up over the existing content, only Ok and cancel buttons are dojo format and json response and that Grid format should popup.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually need to open a new window, you could use [Dijit Dialog](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html). The basic idea would be to create a dialog and set the dialog's content to your content. Assuming you're using a reasonably modern version of Dojo, this might look like (this code is untested):

```
function showTable(tableId) {
    // You wouldn't normally do a `require` in a handler function like 
    // this, but it should work in this case
    require([ 'dijit/Dialog' ], function (Dialog) {
        // Pull the table out of the DOM
        var table = document.getElementById('dist');
        table.parentNode.removeChild(table);

        // Set the table's display style to block so it will be visible
        // when it's re-inserted into the DOM
        table.style.display = 'block';

        // Create and show a new Dialog with the table as it's content
        var dlg = new Dialog({ content: table });
        dlg.show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into the following link where in the second example they have placed the table inside a dialog and on-click they are displaying the dialog which as the table inside.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/Dialog.html